# how to find the number of events or pulses recorded when the value is greater than 0 in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, enumerate, cumsum

I've a data set that represents rainfall every hour in a day. I'm creating column 'E1' which should start from zero and increment every time column 'value' is greater than zero, and stops when column 'value' becomes zero again, again when column 'value' is zero the numbering must continue.

```py
condition = ((df['value'] > 0) & (df['value'].shift(periods=1) == 0))

df['E2'] = (condition).cumsum()
print(df)
    hour  value  E2
0      0    0.0   0
1      1    0.2   1
2      2    0.2   1
3      3    0.2   1
4      4    0.0   1
5      5    0.2   2
6      6    0.2   2
7      7    0.0   2
8      8    NaN   2
9      9    0.2   2
10    10    0.0   2
11    11    0.0   2
12    12    0.2   3
13    13    0.2   3
14    14    0.0   3
15    15    NaN   3
16    16    0.2   3
17    17    0.0   3
18    18    0.2   4
19    19    0.0   4
20    20    0.2   5
21    21    0.2   5
22    22    NaN   5
23    23    0.0   5
```

E1 represents the event number, an event can last 1 or several hours, an event should only be considered when the cell before the start of the event is zero and the cell after the last data is equal to zero

I'm stuck, trying to list the events. Should get:

```py
    hour  value  E2
0      0    0.0   0
1      1    0.2   1
2      2    0.2   1
3      3    0.2   1
4      4    0.0   0
5      5    0.2   2
6      6    0.2   2
7      7    0.0   0
8      8    NaN   0
9      9    0.2   0
10    10    0.0   0
11    11    0.0   0
12    12    0.2   3
13    13    0.2   3
14    14    0.0   0
15    15    NaN   0
16    16    0.2   0
17    17    0.0   0
18    18    0.2   4
19    19    0.0   0
20    20    0.2   0
21    21    0.2   0
22    22    NaN   0
23    23    0.0   0
```

Comment: Seems like hour 9 should be event 3, right?

Comment: Hour 20 and 21 should be 5, right?  Hour 9 doesn't qualify because of the NaN.

Comment: No, hour 9 not is a event, because the previous cell is NaN, it is only an event if the previous cell is zero

Comment: I mean, doesn't qualify OP's logic, but is OP's logic correct for the real world problem? Is the ultimate goal to count rain events? Because hour 8 is NaN, we don't know if hour 9 is the START of the third rain event, but we know it's part of the third rain event, right?

Comment: Hour 20 and 21 like 9. not is a event, because after hour 21 is NaN, an event starts and ends at 0

Comment: Ok, only you would know what you want this code to measure. If you're saying that if every run of rain is preceded or succeeded by a NaN, the desired output is to say that there were zero rain events, then your desired output matches that logic. You should add some checks for isna() to your code.

Comment: So, you are saying that there has to be a continuous series of non-NaNs that begins and ends with a 0?  That's more than you can do with a single statement.  You  need a loop.

Comment: is that we can only count rain events that are complete, I mean they start and end at zero, but if there is NaN at the beginning or end, we do not know if NaN was 0 or another value, so it should not be considered

Comment: Exactly Tim! "So, you are saying that there has to be a continuous series of non-NaNs that begins and ends with a 0?", but I don't know how to do that, I'm new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this an odd criteria, but here's how to compute your "event" numbers.  Because you're looking both forward and backward, there's no way to do this in a vectorized way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
  0.0,
  0.2,
  0.2,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  0.2,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  np.nan,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.2,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  np.nan,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  0.2,
  0.0,
  0.2,
  0.2,
  np.nan,
  0.0
]

data = [[k] for k in data]
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['data'])
print(df)

nxt = 1
nums = np.zeros(len(df['data']), dtype=int)
start = None
for ndx,v in enumerate(df['data']):
    if np.isnan(v):
        start = None
    elif not v:
        if start is not None and start < ndx:
            nums[start:ndx] = nxt
            nxt += 1
        start = ndx+1

df['E1'] = nums
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    data
0    0.0
1    0.2
2    0.2
3    0.2
4    0.0
5    0.2
6    0.2
7    0.0
8    NaN
9    0.2
10   0.0
11   0.0
12   0.2
13   0.2
14   0.0
15   NaN
16   0.2
17   0.0
18   0.2
19   0.0
20   0.2
21   0.2
22   NaN
23   0.0
    data  E1
0    0.0   0
1    0.2   1
2    0.2   1
3    0.2   1
4    0.0   0
5    0.2   2
6    0.2   2
7    0.0   0
8    NaN   0
9    0.2   0
10   0.0   0
11   0.0   0
12   0.2   3
13   0.2   3
14   0.0   0
15   NaN   0
16   0.2   0
17   0.0   0
18   0.2   4
19   0.0   0
20   0.2   0
21   0.2   0
22   NaN   0
23   0.0   0
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was stuck with this. It seems like an odd criteria, but I can only count it as a rain event if the record is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure why the NaNs should matter.  If the last known state was "not raining" and the current state is "raining", that should be an event.

Comment: Sure you can vectorise it... https://www.online-python.com/e82zgclvpG (done on a phone, so a bit messy)

Comment: Minor tweak ; https://www.online-python.com/rjKYmetDCL